# How to get bank url by debit/credit card image?

Tags: android

I am developing an app to capture an image of debit/credit card and redirect the bank URL of that card. Is there any idea to get bank URL API? because we are not supposed to develop own web service to retrieve the URL...Please Guide me what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's an image->url webservice ready for your use.

You will need some form of image handling algoritm. An easy way to do this is just measure the amount of colour in the card. Lots of green with a bit of red -> Bank A. All black -> Bank B. There are of course lots of ways to do this, few are easy and you will likely depend on background, lighting and so on.

Once you have a way to distinguish a card you will need a database, either locally on the phone or a web service that helps you go from image data to bank url.

Comment: Yes, You may right...I should make own database locally or web service  to retrieve bank URL...Thanks for your suggestion...

Comment: Finally,I had found solution for my app. I had used ABBY OCR Image Processing SDK from http://www.http://ocrsdk.com/ to detect the text on the debit/credit card. OCR can detect most of the text. I want to detect only Bank name and it is working...! I did not use database because it is on testing level...I am just comparing few strings of bank names....